# Does container sets session id in cookie in second response to client if Cookies disabled on client side?

Tags: session, servlets, cookies

If client disables cookies, then in the second response to client(not the first one) does the Container sets session id in Cookie? I know it will go for URL appending, but will it avoid setting the session id in cookie in the second response? OR the Container always sets session id in cookie irrespective of Cookies enabled/disabled on client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer to this tutorial [here](http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/url-rewriting-for-session-management.php) which describes how url rewritting works .

the browser first it will try to use cookies , when it fails it will use the url rewritting (appending) , yes it will not set the session id in the cookie .

Hope that Helps .

Comment: Agreed. I happened to check this in a small program today. Basically with cookies disabled, request.getCookies() will return null. So, having the session id in cookie is definitely not possible when disabled. Thanks for the answer!